# How to change the format of a number in a pandas column?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large DataFrame of numbers but each individual number  follows a different format. I want to use a regular expression to replace a large amount of them with a 111-111-1111 format

```
numbers["numbers"].replace('^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$, "/*/*/*-/*/*/*-/*/*/*/*", regex=True')
```

it should take a number found by the expression and keep the base number but change its format. 1234567890 should equal 123-456-7890

Comment: Try `df["numbers"].str.replace('^(?:\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?(\d{3})\)?[\s.-]?(\d{3})[\s.-]?(\d{4})$, r"\1-\2-\3")`

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
df["numbers"] = df["numbers"].str.replace('^(?:\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?(\d{3})\)?[\s.-]?(\d{3})[\s.-]?(\d{4})$', r'\1-\2-\3')
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\+\d{1,2}\s)?` - an optional sequence of
- `\(?` - an optional `(`
- `(\d{3})` - Group 1: three digits
- `\)?` - an optional `)`
- `[\s.-]?` - an optional whitespace, `.` or `-`
- `(\d{3})` - Group 2: three digits
- `[\s.-]?` - an optional whitespace, `.` or `-`
- `(\d{4})`  - Group 3: four digits
- `$` - end of string.

The `\x` in the replacement pattern (`r'\1-\2-\3'`) are placeholders for the values captured with corresponding groups.